# How to customize react-select component?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styles, react-select

I have a little problem with `react-select` component restyling. If you take a look on their [official doc](https://react-select.com/styles) you'll see all the attributes that can be restyled. The problem I have is that around the text I write there's blue borders, and can't remove them. Also around the container.

[image]

If I inspect it here's what I get:

[image]

It has as id `react-select-3-input` and can't remove that even if I write directly on chrome inspection let alone doing it in the code.

I am using nextjs as framework and I added a file **style.css** and import it into `_app.tsx`. I tried adding this to see what happens:

```
#react-select-2-input {
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40;
  background-color: red;
}
```

But nothing happens.

How do you think I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for react-select you can see that the docs steer you towards using emotion more than straight forward CSS.

When implementing this you work should do something like this:

```
const reactSelectStyles = {
    singleValue: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        color: 'inherit',
    }),
    menu: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        'z-index': 9,
    }),
    multiValue: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        color: state.isDisabled ? "#000" : "#fff",
    }),
};
```

This will create an object that you then can use for styling

```
<Select
    styles={reactSelectStyles}
/>
```

Provided in the code above makes sure that the default styling is included (so you can omit it if you want to) and the state can be used to do render different styles depending on the state of the react-select.

I would say that you overall will have a harder time solving this using regular CSS since react-select (using emotion) will generate dynamic CSS classes that does not collide with each other.

Comment: Ofcourse I did it like this for the other parts. My problem is with the blue box you can see around the text. I can't access it through emotion, so I tried with the classic css. The problem is that I cannot access it even using the inspection of Chrome.